# Where to store users followings/followers? User's document of Followings collection? Fat document VS. polymorphic documents

Tags: mongodb, meteor

What I'm talking about is:

```
Meteor.users.findOne() =
{
  _id: "..."
  ...
  followers: {
    users: Array[], // ["someUserId1", "someUserId2"]
    pages: Array[]  // ["somePageId1", "somePageId2"]
  }
}
```

vs.

```
Followings.findOne() =
{
  _id: "..."
  followeeId: "..."
  followeeType: "user"
  followerId: "..."
}
```

I found second one totally inefficient because I need to use smartPublish to publish user's followers.

```
Meteor.smartPublish('userFollowers', function(userId) {
  var coursors = [],
      followings = Followings.find({followeeId: userId});
  followings.forEach(function(following) {
    coursors.push(Meteor.users.find({_id: following.followerId}));
  });
  return coursors;
});
```

And I can't filter users inside the iron-router. I cache subscriptions so there may be more users than I need.

I want to do something like this:

```
data: function() {
  return {
    users: Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: Meteor.user().followers.users}})
  };
},
```

A bad thing about using nested arrays inside the Document is that if I've added an item to followers.users[], the whole array will be sent back to the client.

So what do you think? Is it better to keep such data inside the user Document so it'll become fat? May be it's a 'Meteor way' of solving such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a better idea to keep it nested inside the user document. Storing it in a separate collection leads to a lot of unnecessary duplication, and every time the publish function is run you have to scan the entire collection again. If you're worrying about the arrays growing too large, in most cases, don't (generally, a full-text novel only takes a few hundred kb). Plus, if you're publishing your user document already, you don't have to pull any new documents into memory; you already have everything you need.

This [MongoDB blog post](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) seems to advocate a similar approach (see one-to-many section). It might be worth checking out.

Comment: It's my very first hour learning MongoDB and I can't explain how your post gave me a huge understanding. Coming from my MySQL, Thanks this I can redesign my database in a whole new way and remove all those extra Tables.

Comment: No problem. That's always encouraging to hear, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be aware of the pros and cons of each option. Unfortunately, your question is mostly opinion based.

Generally, if your follower arrays will be small in size and don't change often, keep them embedded.

Otherwise a dedicated collection is the way to go.

For that case, you might want to take a look at https://atmospherejs.com/cottz/publish which seems very efficient in what it does and very easy to implement syntactically.